# How to create an empty list that will only take string values

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create an empty list, list=[], it should only include string values. i mean to say when i populate this list, the values should get converted into stings only.

Comment: You can't say you need what when you define your list.

Comment: Standard lists don't support this. You should create your own list-like class that'll convert its elements to `str`.

Comment: when you 'populate this list', why not just `str(element)` when appending?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all your values in your list to be Strings, you can use str() and a forloop.

```
#exampel
mylist = [3, "hello 8", 5 , "hi", "good"]
strs = []

for element in mylist:
      strs.append(str(element))

print(strs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small line of code that can turn any of your list to list of string. I believe that you should use this:

```
list_mix = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.55, 5.6] #example of a list
list_str = list(map(lambda x: str(x), list_mix)) #list turned to a list of string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the list in a class with an add method that guards the input